# Japanese (or non-ASCII) urls and curl

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I am trying to access a file at this url: http://www.myurl.com/伊勢/image.jpg.

The urls are predefined and there is no specific format or consistency.

The basic curl function I am using is fine for downloading images from myurl.com, but not when there are Japanese characters contained in the url. I have tried sanitising the url in various ways (such as urlencode, filter_var, and mb_convert_encoding), with no success.

If I visit the url directly from the browser, it's fine - so the only problem that I can't resolve is the handling of non-ASCII (Japanese) characters in the curl function.

My question is - how can this be resolved? Is there a curl option that can be included in the function in order to read the url as a browser will?

Answer (score 3):

> If I visit the url directly from the browser, it's fine

That means your browser encode "伊勢" (like %E4%BC%8A%E5%8B%A2) and send request in background. But still keep the look in your browser address box.

My suggestion is use http debugger, like "firebug" in firefox or "developer tools" in chrome.

Check the "network" tab and find the REAL request parameters in its detail page. Then you can find what your browser sent.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. You are correct about the "%E4%BC%8A%E5%8B%A2" type format that the browser interprets the url in. But what is the encoding of "%E4%BC%8A%E5%8B%A2"?

Comment: @eddz The encoding depends on your browser and your locale. Result will be different for Shift-JIS and UTF-8. That's why I told you to debug the HTTP info in your browser to find the right encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special.
I have created a php file in UTF-8 (using notepad's `save as` `encoding` `UTF-8` ):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://rp.postcontrol.ru/伊勢.txt';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if ( $result =  curl_exec($ch) )
{
    echo $result;
}
else
echo "cURL error: ".curl_error($ch);


curl_close( $ch );
```

You may take the PHP file at http://rp.postcontrol.ru/eddz.php.txt

It works for me and returns (伊勢.txt is in UTF-8 too):

```
おはようございます eddz さん.
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the path parameter as a url encoded string and it will work.
 ex:

```
$url = 'http://rp.postcontrol.ru/';
$filename = urlencode("伊勢.txt");

$url .= $filename;
```